# Drawing text on the modelview matrix using QuickFont/OpenTK

Tags: opentk

I just started using QuickFont and for what I can understand It's only allow you to write text on the projection matrix. My question is simple is it possible to use quickfont to render text on the ViewModel and how can i do it?

Thanks.